# Expressjs Multipart Upload Fail but POST Persists

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have an issue where the `error` statement in the `upload()` function is being triggered, but not stopping the form submission from being processed and sending a redirect as indicated in the error half of my if statement. What is missing from my `.post` route that is allowing the remainder of my route methods to run?

Illegal file extension format in the upload variable definition is what is throwing the error.

**POST**:

```
.post(function(req, res){
        var s3FilePath = [];

        upload(req, res, function(err){
            if(err){
                req.flash('error', err);
                res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
            }

            var uploadedFiles = req.files;

            //Configure Uploaded S3 File Path strings based on environment for use in DB
            for (var prop in uploadedFiles){
                console.log(uploadedFiles[prop].key);
                if (app.get('env') === 'production' || app.get('env') === 'staging'){
                    s3FilePath = 'https://files.test-site.com/' + uploadedFiles[prop].key;
                } else {
                    s3FilePath.push(uploadedFiles[prop].location);
                }
            }

            models.Blog.create({
                title: req.body.title,
                type: req.body.type,
                userId: req.user.userId     
            }).then(function(blog){
                var files = _.map(s3FilePath, function (file) {
                    return {
                        file: file,
                        blogId: blog.blogId
                    };
                });
                return models.BlogFile.bulkCreate(files); 
            }).then(function(){
                req.flash('info', 'Blog was successfully created.');
                res.redirect('/app');
            });
        });
    });
```

`upload` variable definition:

```
   var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: options.Bucket,
            contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
            acl: options.ACL,
            key: function(req, file, cb){
                var fileNameFormatted = file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                cb(null, req.user.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted);
            }
        }),
        fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
            if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|csv|xls|xlsb|xlsm|xlsx)$/)){
                return cb('One of your selected files is not supported', false);
            }
            cb(null, true);
        }
    }).array('fileUpload', 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a return statement after redirect. remember the script is imperative it will continue executing. or use res.end() to terminate all subsequent request.

```
  if(err){
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
            return;
        }
```

the redirect call does not alter the state flow of your code, it only modifies the route, thus the next line is executed which is `var uploadedFiles = req.files;` which is illegal and throws a Illegal file extension format.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for the detailed explanation